# Changing texbox values from another project C#

Tags: c#, project, kinect

where is form with layout, with 3 textboxes. Kinect coor X, Y and Z.

I also have second project, where, I get coordinates of hand from Kinect. Main project is referencing second project.

Now I need update these textboxes, with coordinates, which I get from Kinect in second project. How can I do it? When I will try, add main project to references in second project, visual studio says it is circular dependency.

Comment: Why must there be two projects?

Comment: Can you return your coordinates from the second project to the first project, then change the values of the textbox in the project that actually contains them?